# get only a part of text() with xpath

Tags: xpath, scrapy, substring, response

I'm trying to get the array of authors of this website:

http://www.intechopen.com/books/latest/1/list

with this xpath:

```
response.xpath("//div[@id='sizer']/div[@id='content']/div[@class='grid']/div[@class='main-content']/div[@id='tc']/div/ul[@class='book-listing entity-listing']/li/dl/dd[@class='meta']/text()[count(preceding-sibling::br) = 0]").extract()
```

but i want only the names, without the "editor", how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After selecting the text, use the regular expression function [`re()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) with a capture group in order to exclude the text you do not want:

```
response.xpath("//div[@id='sizer']/div[@id='content']/div[@class='grid']/div[@class='main-content']/div[@id='tc']/div/ul[@class='book-listing entity-listing']/li/dl/dd[@class='meta']/text()[count(preceding-sibling::br) = 0]")
  .re(r'Editor\s*(.*)')
```